# How to make a discord.py answer when mentioned in channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a bot that does mod-related things like kick, ban, mute, etc. I wanted to add a feature where the bot will respond with a guide to the help page when you mention the bot. I got the basics down, but when I mention the bot, it responds with the message even with other text included. How would I make it so that it does not respond to the message if you have other text included? I code in cogs so if you could also include that in your code that would be great! Thank you ahead of time.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class events(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client

  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_message(self, message):
    if self.client.user.mentioned_in(message):
      await message.channel.send("My prefix is `m.`\nTry `m.help` for help with commands")

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(events(client))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class events(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
    print("Test intiialised")

  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_message(self, ctx):
    print(ctx.content)
    if self.client.user.mentioned_in(ctx) and len(ctx.content.split(' ')) == 1 and ctx.content[-1] == ">" and ctx.content[0] == '<':
      await ctx.channel.send("My prefix is `m.`\nTry `m.help` for help with commands")

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(events(client))
```

This probably isn't the best way to do it, however, as you aren't using a function to call it, and therefore can't count the amount of arguments, I can't think of a better way to do it.  Perhaps someone else can. The `len(ctx.content.split(' ')) == 1` ensures that there's no spaces in the message, and the `ctx.content[-1] == ">" and ctx.content[0] == '<'` ensures it starts and ends with </> to make sure it doesn't run from someone going @botnameword where there isn't a space.  However if someone did @botnameword> it may still run but that probably isn't likely to happen.  Hopefully this is a good enough solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. This did work. as he said if anyone else has a better way of doing it feel free to answer my question/problem.